# Which type of Java GUI will let me have a "search" text box for the user, with clickable matching results appearing as they start to type?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, searchbar

I've done a couple of basic GUIs before, using the JFrame form in NetBeans. I noticed that there are some other choices for form, such as JPanel, etc.. I'm not sure what the best one to use is for what I'm trying to do, and if I pick the best form or type of GUI, I'm still not sure which objects/buttons etc. would be best to put on it. I'm willing to watch tutorials if I have to do something more complicated than a basic JFrame (it would be great if someone told me what I have to research to learn how to do what I want).

Basically, my program has most of the code written already, but no GUI yet. My program has a static ArrayList of objects. Each object represents one of my friends from an online game I play, including their name and stats. In the GUI, I want there to be a text box where the user can search for the name of one of my friends. But as the user starts typing (before they hit enter or click anything), the results for what they typed in so far would appear below the search bar as clickable buttons (so if they type "An" then perhaps Andrew and Anna would pop up). Then, the user can click one of the name buttons, and who they clicked on will appear further below in a String. The user can then search for someone else as many times as they want, with each result being added to the String. Code I write will then do something with this String, which will basically represent a list of names.

I don't need someone to explain how to do this, but I just want to know what type of thing I need for this. I don't know much about GUI, but I will look up any tutorials needed to do this, even if I have to make an app. Thank you very much.

EDIT: Maybe I don't need to say this, but I'm hoping to make the GUI into a .exe so that people who don't know anything about programming can download and use it. Also, the program relies on data in a text file, and I don't want people downloading the .exe to be prevented from accessing the built-in text file easily. I'm only saying this extra info in case it affects what type of GUI is the best.

Duplicate question accusation response: stackoverflow is telling me that my question has been identified as a possible duplicate to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758313/filtering-jlist-based-on-jtextfield), and wants me to explain why my question is different. Basically, my question is about which general GUI strategy is best for making clickable search results appear just from a user typing in a search bar. The other question is specifically about using JTextField and JList, which is only one strategy option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering JList based on JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758313/filtering-jlist-based-on-jtextfield)

Answer (score 0):

`JTextField` is probably what your are looking for.

Why do you want your GUI to be `.exe`?
Wouldnt be `.jar` better?

Comment: Thank you. The reason I didn't want to use .jar is because on some computers supposedly, .jar files don't do anything when clicked on, unless a setting is changed. I don't want other people using my program to have to worry about changing settings, because I want it to be as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should consider developing JavaFX. I've completed one project. The framework is easier to understand.

1. You design your GUI layout using SceneBuilder (drag&drop). Make sure you define unique ID for each of your textfield, label, image, etc
2. Create Java Controller class to handle the FXML elements you define in Step 1
3. Create other helper classes to help you reduce your program complexities.
4. Use antBuild to create the .exe

Here is the useful tutorial link to help you get started:
[JavaFX Tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/)

Comment: 1. drag and drop is not automatically better, because the code which will be produced may be waaaay worse than anything you code by hand. 2. the more helper classes you have to create, the more complex your program becomes. 3. i doubt its possible/useful to create an exe with ant

Comment: Drag & drop is better coz you wont waste time with designing the template which can be time consuming. I've used SceneBuilder before. It's possible to create .exe file with antBuild. It's as simple as: run the build.xml with Ant: (1) Right-click on the build.xml file | Run As | Ant Build. (2) If everything was successful, you should find the native bundle (exe) in the folder build/deploy/bundles

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check out that tutorial.

Comment: @AzaSuhaza surely its faster to simply drag and drop all the components in place, yet you will generate a sh*t load of code which is totally useless. also you will probably miss things like resize behavior etc.

Comment: So you prefer to create fxml using notepad++ than SceneBuilder (which offer drag & drop elements) ?? I'm writing based on my experience. After I finish with arranging the look and feel of my GUI app, then only I'll use the codes to apply specific behaviour to the element